# matplotlibで折れ線グラフを書く方法

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

以下の問題のグラフの書き方をおしえてください！！

> 「for文、range」を用いることで、データ：
>
> ```
> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,.......496,497,498,499,500]
> y = [sin(1),sin(2),.............sin(499),sin(500)]
> ```
>
> matplotlib を用いて折れ線グラフを描け

Comment: 変数x、yもプログラム中で生成するのでしょうか？問題中にて用意されているのでしょうか？　また、作成途中でも良いので自身で作成されたコードはありませんか？

Comment: たぶん生成すると思います。最近始めたばかりで全く分からなくて白旗状態です助けていただけませんか？

Comment: 独学でしょうか？ 学校の講義/演習とか何かの学習コースなら、事前に説明を受けていたり参考資料が提示されていると思われるので、それを参照してください。独学なら単独で検索するか何か体系的な学習の出来そうなコース等(有料でも無料でも)を探して学んでみてください。まあ単純にはこんな記事を読み解いてみてください。[Exponential graphs in Python without using NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59012980/9014308), [Python how to plot graph sine wave](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22566692/9014308)

Comment: 参考: [Plotting sine and cosine with Matplotlib and Python - Python for Undergraduate Engineers](https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/plotting-sin-cos-with-matplotlib.html)

Answer (score 0):

質問ですが、なぜforとrangeを使わなきゃいけない？

通常の場合は、下記の通り使えばOK：

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(1,500,num=500,endpoint=True)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
plt.plot(x, y, '-o')
plt.show()
```

ループでデータを生成して(linspaceを使わず)描く：

```
x=[]     #listタイプ
y=[]     #listタイプ
for i in range(500):
    x1.append(i+1)    #list.append(a) aをlistの最後に加えarrayじゃ無理
    y1.append(np.sin(i+1))
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
plt.plot(x, y, '-o')
plt.show()
```

pythonはループに弱いから、効率のためできる限り多重ループを回避してね

Comment: ありがとうございます！　問題でそうあったのでやり方が気になったので質問しました。

Comment: そうか、多分この　「for文、range」を用いること　はデータを生成する目的だと憶測する。一般、折れ線を描くにループは使わないんだ。答えを更新するね。

Answer (score 0):

> 「for文、range」を用いることで

課題の前提条件を遵守するのであれば以下の様に。

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import sin

x = list(range(1, 501))
y = []
for v in x:
  y.append(sin(v))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

参考までに、Python 3.8 以降であれば以下の様にも書けます。

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import sin

plt.plot((x:=list(range(1, 501))), list(map(sin, x)))
plt.show()
```

Comment: 丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございます！これを散布図にするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？何度もすみません